# mostrar mas informacion dentro de un tr JQUERY

Tags: jquery

tengo la siguiente tabla html:

```js
$('[ver-mas-info]').on("click",function() {

$(this).parents("tr").addClass("show_mas_info");

});
```

```css
tr.show_mas_info td:not(.td_mas_info):not(.td-opc){
display:none;
}
tr.show_mas_info td.td_mas_info{
display:block;
}

tr td.td_mas_info{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tbl-e1" tbl-id="clientes">
<thead>
<tr><th class="waves-effect tfsort" style="min-width: 105px; width: 105px; cursor: pointer;" data-tsort="desc">Fecha<span class="caret"></span></th>
<th width="80%" data-tsort="desc" class="tfsort" style="cursor: pointer;">Cliente<span class="caret"></span></th>
<th width="20%" data-tsort="disabled" data-tfilter="disabled" class="disabled-sort">Mascotas</th>
<th data-tsort="disabled" data-tfilter="disabled" class="disabled-sort">Celular</th>
<th data-tsort="disabled" data-tfilter="disabled" class="disabled-sort"></th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr tr-pedido-id="" pedido-estado="estado-">

<td class="td_mas_info" colspan="4">Hola</td>


<td>16-12-2020</td>
<td class="bold">nombre de cliente</td>
<td>Miribom, Kaiser</td>
<td style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;"><a href="tel:976584269" class="tooltip">976584269<span class="tooltiptext tooltiptext-bottomarrow" style="width:100px">Llamar</span></a></td>
<td width="20" class="td-opc" style="vertical-align:middle" td-id="opciones">
<div class="flex">
<button class="btn-ico min tooltip" ver-mas-info=""><span class="tooltiptext tooltiptext-bottomarrow" style="width:100px">Vista rapida</span></button>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Al dar click en el boton vista rapida me muestra el td con clase `.td_mas_info` y oculta los td que no tengas esa clase.

La cosa es que `.td_mas_info` tiene `colspan = 4` pero al momento de mostrarlo no me detecta el colspan

Les agradeceria bastante la ayuda.

Nota: el td tiene que estar generado de manera estatica ya que alli coloco la informacion que me genera mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifique el display de tu columna, la tenias como block, y la deje a table-cell, para que se comporte como una celda de una tabla.

```js
$('[ver-mas-info]').on("click",function() {
  $(this).parents("tr").addClass("show_mas_info");
});
```

```css
tr.show_mas_info td:not(.td_mas_info):not(.td-opc){
  display:none;
}

tr.show_mas_info td.td_mas_info {
    display: table-cell;
}

tr td.td_mas_info{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tbl-e1" tbl-id="clientes">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="waves-effect tfsort" style="min-width: 105px; width: 105px; cursor: pointer;" data-tsort="desc">
        Fecha<span class="caret"></span>
      </th>
      <th width="80%" data-tsort="desc" class="tfsort" style="cursor: pointer;">
        Cliente<span class="caret"></span>
      </th>
      <th width="20%" data-tsort="disabled" data-tfilter="disabled" class="disabled-sort">
        Mascotas
      </th>
      <th data-tsort="disabled" data-tfilter="disabled" class="disabled-sort">
        Celular
      </th>
      <th data-tsort="disabled" data-tfilter="disabled" class="disabled-sort"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr tr-pedido-id="" pedido-estado="estado-">
      <td class="td_mas_info" colspan="4">Hola</td>
      <td>16-12-2020</td>
      <td class="bold">nombre de cliente</td>
      <td>Miribom, Kaiser</td>
      <td style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">
        <a href="tel:976584269" class="tooltip">976584269
          <span class="tooltiptext tooltiptext-bottomarrow" style="width:100px">Llamar</span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td width="20" class="td-opc" style="vertical-align:middle" td-id="opciones">
        <div class="flex">
          <button class="btn-ico min tooltip" ver-mas-info="">
            <span class="tooltiptext tooltiptext-bottomarrow" style="width:100px">Vista rapida</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: gracias amigo, el codigo funciono